# scala: how to associate data from a file?

Tags: scala, loops

I'm starting with scala and i'm trying to associate values for every lines of my file.
Let's say I have this simple text file as input:

```
key1,data1#data2  
key2,data3#data4#data5
```

I want my output to be:

```
key1,data1
key1,data2
key2,data3
key2,data4
key2,data5
```

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
Source.fromFile("test").getLines.map { line =>
val data = line.split(",")
for(v <- data(1).split("#"))
{
(data(0),v)
}
}.foreach(println)
```

Any hint ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close:

```
def parseLine(str: String) = { 
    val Array(key, values) = str.split(",")
    for(value <- values.split("#")) yield key -> value
}

val lines = List(
    "key1,data1#data2",  
    "key2,data3#data4#data5"
)

lines.flatMap(parseLine).foreach(println)

(key1,data1)
(key1,data2)
(key2,data3)
(key2,data4)
(key2,data5)
```

Your particular problem was in

```
for(v <- data(1).split("#")) {
  (data(0),v)
}
```

you've build result `(data(0),v)` tuple, but were not returning it anywhere (e.g. with yield)

Comment: Thank you! I was definitely missing this yield feature ans somehow the use of flatMap instead of map